# How does NDepend count the parameters number for delegates?

Tags: ndepend

We set some quality contraint on our code, using NDEPEND CQL request:

> WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT TOP 10 METHODS WHERE NbParameters > 6

When defining a delegate with 5 arguments, for example:

```
delegate void MyDelegate(IArg arg1, IArg arg2, IArg arg3, IArg arg4, IArg arg5);
```

Then the quality constraint breaks on a function which is not present in source code (but probably in compiled code) and has 2 addtional arguments:

```
BeginInvoke(IArg, IArg, IArg, IArg, IArg, AsyncCallback,Object)
```

How to work around this impediment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CQL cannot easily solve this issue, but [Code Rule over LINQ (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) released since NDepend v4 can.

CQLinq comes with facilities to define what is **JustMyCode**, hence eliminate generated methods like *BeginInvoke(IArg, IArg, IArg, IArg, IArg, AsyncCallback,Object)*. This is explained in: [Defining the code base view JustMyCode with notmycode prefix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CQLinq_Syntax.aspx#NotMyCode)

Basically the default and customizable code rule [Discard generated Types from JustMyCode](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Discard_generated_Types_from_JustMyCode.html) discard delegate types, and their methods, because they are always generated.

```
// <Name>Discard generated Types from JustMyCode</Name>
// --- Make sure to make this query richer to discard generated types from NDepend rules results ---
notmycode
from t in Application.Types where

  // Resources, Settings, or typed DataSet generated types for example, are tagged with this attribute
  t.HasAttribute ("System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute".AllowNoMatch()) ||

  // Delegate types are always generated
  t.IsDelegate ||

  // Discard ASP.NET page types generated by aspnet_compiler.exe
  // See: http://www.ndepend.com/FAQ.aspx#ASPNET
  t.ParentNamespace.Name.EqualsAny("ASP", "__ASP") ||

  // Discard generated type ContractException
  t.Name == "__ContractsRuntime+ContractException" ||
  t.FullName == "System.Diagnostics.Contracts.RuntimeContractsAttribute" ||
  t.FullName == "System.Diagnostics.Contracts.__ContractsRuntime" ||

  // Discard all types declared in a folder path containing the word "generated"
  (t.SourceFileDeclAvailable &&
   t.SourceDecls.All(s => s.SourceFile.FilePath.ParentDirectoryPath.ToString().ToLower().Contains("generated")))

select new { t, t.NbILInstructions }
```